# 32-bit DLL causing UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: java, windows, gcc, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to create 32-bit and 64-bit versions of a library.

**Command:**

```
gcc -D_WIN32 -O2 -shared -I%JAVA_HOME%\include -I%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32 \
-Ic:\OpenSSL-Win32\include -Lc:\OpenSSL-Win32 -leay32 -Lc:\Windows\System32 \
-lnetapi32 -std=c99 -lm -o osaccess-win32.dll osaccess.c
```

... replacing 32 with 64 where appropriate on the different machines.

They both build ok, and the 64-bit works in my application.  However, my 32-bit one causes a `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` error when it tries to load it:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.suture.self.Util.OSAccess.osExec(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
```

I have explored all of the normal avenues for this type of error (ensuring 32-bit `jni.h` file used, checking `java.library.path` etc) but everything seems fine.

I don't know if this means anything, but when I ran `dumpbin /exports <dll-name>` against both dll's, I noticed a small discrepancy.

**32-bit**

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
      1    0 00001D1F Java_com_suture_self_Util_OSAccess_osExec@12
```

**64-bit**

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
      1    0 0000200E Java_com_suture_self_Util_OSAccess_osExec
```

What is the significance of the **@12** in the 32-bit DLL?

Comment: the @12 is name mangling that gcc does. Did you export your function declaractions with `extern "C"`?

Comment: No, my C code doesn't contain that.  It works on all other platforms I have tested (Linux64, Sparc, Win64) just not Win32.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding these options

`-Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -m32 -shared`

to your link line when compiling for 32-bit.  The --add-stdcall-alias will create non-decorated/non-mangled function names.

Comment: Brilliant, that did the trick.  Works fine now on 32-bit.  Although using `dumpbin` it shows me both an unmangled and a mangled function for osExec.  Anyway, thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @SutureSelf  Yes, the --add-stdcall-alias just adds a non-mangled alias to the mangled function, so they both will be present post-link.